# Voltage measurement

Tags: electric-circuits, voltage, batteries

[image]Why does multimeter show 0 V ?

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/169164/

Comment: I see that you changed the image. But the answer is the same. There is no connection  shown between the negative battery terminal and the ground. The negative terminal of the battery cannot be considered  grounded unless physically connected to ground. So there is still  no complete circuit for the multimeter to draw current.

Comment: Yes. The second image is the problem. Thanks you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multimeters I’m aware of need to draw a little  current from the circuit, without affecting the parameter being measured, in order to make the measurement. You  don’t have a complete circuit. If you made the measurement across the terminals of one of the batteries it would give you the voltage since the circuit is completed within the battery.

Hope this helps